# How does the light PropsType affect the CSS in reactstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am learning React via the course on Coursera. Here is the part where the tutor didn't mention how we can utilize the below "special" mechanism for CSS styling.

In my HeaderComponent.js file, the tutor pass the data as props to the `Navbar` pre-built component as below.

```
...
<Navbar light expand="md">
...
</Navbar>
...
```

Below is the documentation of `Navbar` properties([Link](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/))

```
Navbar.propTypes = {
  light: PropTypes.bool,
  dark: PropTypes.bool,
  fixed: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  role: PropTypes.string,
  expand: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.string]),
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string])
  // pass in custom element to use
}
```

In the App.css file

```
.navbar-light {
  background-color: rgb(211, 81, 81);
}
```

To my surprise, this CSS selector works! From what I knew, to use a class in JSX we should use `classNama="navbar-light"` in the `Navbar` tag.

I would like to learn more about this, how can I utilize this mechanism?
For example, if I have a `Card` reactstrap component, can I use `<Card body>` then in CSS

```
.card-body{
  background-color: rgb(211, 81, 81);
}
```

since the `body` prop is bool type as well as below

```
Card.propTypes = {
  // Pass in a Component to override default element
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  inverse: PropTypes.bool,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  body: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string
};
```

to specify the color of the Card? I can't find any guide online on how to utilize this mechanism.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

reactstrap uses a utility called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) which helps you construct a list of class names.

Example:

```
const classes = classnames("class1", "class2");

// `classes` is set to the string "class1 class2"
// Not so useful yet, but read on ...
```

It also lets you perform boolean checks to decide whether to include a class or not.

The following example creates a string of class names that contains the class `card-base`, and `card-large` if `large` is true.

```
const classes = classnames(
  "card-base",
  "card-large": large,
);

// If `large` evaluates to `true`, this will result in "card-base card-large"
```

`large` can be passed in as a prop. Here's a working example:

```js
import classnames from "classnames";

const Card = ({ large, className }) => {
  const classes = classnames(
    className, // Keep the classes that are passed in with the `className` prop
    "card-base",
    "card-large": large,
  );

  return <div className={classes}>... rest of the component ...</div>
}

// Validate the props:
Card.propTypes = {
  large: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string // The user can still provide their own classes
};
```

Remember to install the classnames package first: `npm install classnames`.

[PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) is used to validate the data a component receives. You add the `propTypes` property to a component with a list of props and their expected datatypes, and warnings will be shown in the JavaScript console if any validations fail. Prop types have nothing directly to do with CSS or class names. It's a safety mechanism that adds no additional behavior.

Comment: Now I know there is this utility, thanks! But FYI, the `Card` Component is a pre-built component in reactstrap. My question is, can I assume that appending a lowercase pre-built reactstrap Component(like `Card`,`Button`,`Tabs`) with a `-` and any properties key(e.g. `body` and `inverse` in `Card` reactstrap Component) in propsType object will automatically style the Component?

Comment: Not sure if I follow. `propTypes` is only for props validation. It makes sure the component receives the correct props, and that they are of the correct type. The `Card` component in my answer will complain if you use it like `<Card large="hello" />`, because the `large` prop should be a boolean. Adding properties to `propTypes` won't have any other effect; it's a safety mechanism, and some people even remove it automatically before deploying their app because they feel it's only necessary during development.

Comment: Check out how reactstrap's Card component constructs a list of classes: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/d394c45083d5ffbab0b5bc5f63c28c92dc4eb833/src/Card.js#L37-L43 If the `inverse` prop is set, it also adds the class `text-white`. So there's no one-to-one mapping between the props and the CSS classes. More importantly, how reactstrap adds classes to their components is an implementation detail and might be subject to change. You should restrict yourself to the props that the components expose, as this makes up the "interface" of the component. Trying to bypass this is risky.